# Google account authorization for users accessing google docs

Tags: coldfusion, google-docs-api

I am pulling list of docs in coldfusion via google docs API. I want users to click on the link and get signed in automatically in google docs, with my username and password. Google should not ask user name and password from them. 
I tried out this example http://cfgoogle.riaforge.org/

Till now I am able to pull up list of documents I have on my google docs account.
But I want anyone to click those link and get automatically signed in as me. And able to access my documents. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that accessing the documents *as you* is not possible via the end-user's browser.  Google will set a cookie on your computer identifying your session.  This allows you access to documents, mail, etc.  whatever is linked in your account.  For them to be able to access the documents using your account, they would have to be logged in as you.  You can't do that directly from your application, because you can only write cookies for your domain (oversimplification, but basically....)

There may, however, be a workaround.

One option would be to use the API to automatically share the document with the user.  That is, they provide their Google ID (not password) and you share with their account.  This is probably what I would try.

Alternately, you could proxy requests for documents, although this opens up a whole 'nother can of worms.

Comment: Plus signing in with another account can (and will) be inappropriate for people already signed in with _own_ account.